# The page you selected contains a list that does not exist

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I make in root put a list wchich have not exist. And I can get to the site. It show me 
“The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.” How could I solwe this problem? Please help

Answer (score 1):

If the page needs a list, why not just create an empty list for that page?  I don't quite understand your question (sorry!), but I assume you have a page that is trying to access a non-existant list, so just create an empty one if you don't need it.

Comment: But it making in root site. I cant create agein a site.

Comment: I put a list at edit a site.

Comment: I can't get the site by internet explorer or any of site. I can only get a Site by Sharepoint Designer.

Comment: Are you using Sharepoint Designer?  All webpages have associated lists to store page information.  So when you create a webpage, it's corresponding list is also created.  You can check this by going into Sharepoint designer, clicking "List and Libraries," and finding the page that runs the error.  From what I understand, you created a page, and did you then move the web code into another page's view?  I'm still not sure what you mean by "root site."

Comment: When You are creating a site colection first you creating root site, and next buld a sites to the root site. When Can I edit a site, not master site on Sharepoint Designer ?

Comment: Okay, what I think is happening is that you need a privilege escalation.  You, as a user, don't have masterpage access, thus not allowing you to create a page, or view it while accessing it from a browser.  Go to Site Actions –> Site Settings –> Master pages and page layouts –> Settings –> Document library settings –> Permissions, and add a group called NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users(Read, Restricted Read).  Here is my source if you want more info http://angler.wordpress.com/tag/the-page-you-selected-contains-a-list-that-does-not-exist/

Comment: If this works, I can change my answer accordingly :)

Comment: No no I am master colection admin but I added a list by edit a Site, and I edited the page.

Comment: And now it din't show me any page.

Comment: I can see that English is not your first language. Maybe it would be easier to understand your problem if you write it in your native language into Google Translate and then post the English result here.

Comment: Then my last attempt at an answer would have to be that when creating the page, some fields in the list are not connected to a term set.  Start removing fields (even default ones) until you find the erring fields.  You can either leave them removed, or add them back, while connecting them to a term set that you create.  Other than this, I have no idea what the problem could be :(  Again, here is my reference if you would like to read more http://www.psclistens.com/blog/2014/4/this-week%E2%80%99s-hair-thinner-the-page-you-selected-contains-a-list-that-does-not-exist.aspx

Comment: I done it by History of a site. I give a link from another site, get the link get to page by Site content and refresh my page from history :)